# Django api and SQLite3. How to do "SELECT * FROM table"?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm using SQLite3 database and when I try to make any api requests like MyClass.objects.all() or MyClass.objects.filter() or MyClass.objects.filter(id=1), I get only first column in table. I can get all colums in raw query, it doesn't work in api. What's wrong?

Here is my models code:

```
class Myclass(models.Model): 
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    api = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Myclass.objects.all() shows me only filename.

Comment: Did you add new fields and then forgot to call `django-admin migratge` ?

Comment: I did it several times

Comment: what do you mean by shows ?
you mean if you do something like
`classList = Myclass.objects.all()
for obj in classList:
    obj.status` 
it has no information ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually I get it:)

It was hard to find out that I need to iterate QuerySet to get all data.

Answer (score 1):

If you just do that in the shell, you get a list of objects, but the list is printed by calling the `__unicode__` method is each object. You have presumably defined that to return just the email value.

However this is just a representation: the query has definitely returned all the columns, and each object in the list will have the correct data.